# How can you check for STDIN input in a Ruby script?

Tags: ruby

I need to check for the presence of STDIN input in a Ruby script, like the `mysql` command can. If nothing is being directed to STDIN, then the script should not attempt to read STDIN.

How can this be done in a cross-platform way?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This is something that's done in Linux a lot:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

str = (STDIN.tty?) ? 'not reading from stdin' : $stdin.read
puts str

>> $ ruby test.rb 
>> not reading from stdin
>> $ echo "reading from stdin" | ruby test.rb 
>> reading from stdin
```

Comment: Any specific reason for using `STDIN` _and_ `$stdin`?