# What does #tty? on STDIN mean / do in ruby?

Tags: ruby, io

Reading the ruby docs isn't overly helpful [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-i-tty-3F):

> Returns true if ios is associated with a terminal device (tty), false
> otherwise.

I was hoping to get some additional resources or explanation to help me understand this better.

For context, I'm writing a little command line program that accepts either a file path or piped content into the ruby executable and am using `#tty?` to determine what is coming in.

Comment: Even when invoked from a console (= tty), your script might still have to read a file, right? I suggest you use the passed argument as file path and if no arguments are passed read from `$stdin`. Even better, use two named arguments where one is parameterized with the file name and the other specifies that input is to be read form `$stdin`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Seems like http://www.jstorimer.com/blogs/workingwithcode/7766125-writing-ruby-scripts-that-respect-pipelines supplies the most concise description of what `#tty?` does:

> Ruby's IO#isatty method (aliased as IO#tty?) will tell you whether or not the IO in question is attached to a terminal. Calling it on $stdout, for instance, when it's being piped will return false.

Here is some relevant info that you may find useful:

- [Detecting stdin content in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7114911/detecting-stdin-content-in-ruby)
- [How can you check for STDIN input in a Ruby script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622046/how-can-you-check-for-stdin-input-in-a-ruby-script)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/273605
- https://gist.github.com/timuruski/6072363

Background meaning via [What do pty and tty mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4426280/what-do-pty-and-tty-mean):

> In UNIX, /dev/tty* is any device that acts like a "teletype", ie, terminal. (Called teletype because that's what we had for terminals in those benighted days.)

In the spirit of the question, here's an example of writing to `/dev/tty` from http://zetcode.com/lang/rubytutorial/io/:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

fd = IO.sysopen "/dev/tty", "w"
ios = IO.new(fd, "w")
ios.puts "ZetCode"
ios.close
```

Comment: Thanks, @SoAwesomeMan. Exactly what I wanted - additional resources with some explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Look at how `grep` handles this situation for the traditional UNIX approach: No file specified? Default to `$stdin` and don't worry about TTY status, maybe someone wants to paste into the terminal. If a filename is specified, read from that and ignore STDIN.

The `tty?` function is there so you can know if you should send things like ANSI escape codes to colour your output. It's not generally a reliable signal of if someone wants to supply input over STDIN.