# Optionally allowing STDIN to be passed to a rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a rake task that I would like to be optionally given stdin, e.g. either of the following could work:

```
rake my_task
cat foo.txt | rake my_task
```

The problem is that I don't have a reliable way to check whether STDIN was given to the program. Here's my current attempt, which just hangs indeterminately:

```
instructions = STDIN.read.split("\n") if STDIN.tty?
```

I added the `STDIN.tty?` after reading [how-can-you-check-for-stdin-input-in-a-ruby-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622046/how-can-you-check-for-stdin-input-in-a-ruby-script). It is returning `true` when I invoke it with `rake my_task` (no stdin)

Comment: hope one of these http://cobwwweb.com/4-ways-to-pass-arguments-to-a-rake-task options work for you

Comment: I think you just need to invert your condition, i.e. you want to read `$stdin` if it’s _not_ a tty (it’s a pipe).

Comment: @matt you are correct, feel free to add answer or I will

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to invert the condition. What you want is to read stdin if it’s *not* a tty:

```
instructions = STDIN.read.split("\n") unless STDIN.tty?
```

Comment: Edited to use unless instead of `if !`